# Is there a difference between "I am male" and "I am a male"?

Tags: meaning, articles, writing-style, tone

Both versions seem grammatically correct to me, since the word "male" can be either a noun or an adjective, so it can be used with and without an article.

But I wonder, is there any difference in meanings of these two phrases? Maybe any difference in tone or style of speech, which is seen only to native speakers?

Comment: There is a grammatical difference.  The first sentence employs "male" as an adjective, while the latter employs it as a noun. In my dialect of English (US), "a male" sounds more technical than the just using "male."

Comment: Highly context-dependent.

Comment: Perhaps. And perhaps you should ask this sort of question on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1):

Not much, but one is an adjective and one is a noun. The difference is very slight, and wouldn't have an impact on the meaning of the sentence.